# Import data from one database table to another database tables using grails

Tags: mysql, grails, import

I am using grails 2.2.1 and mysql for database and want to import data from one database to the database used by grails application.
The database used by grails application is :

```
employeeinfo
```

with table

```
 employee
```

and the fields are

```
id,name,gender,phone,date_of_birth,address
```

and the database from which i want to import is

```
 employeedata
```

with table

```
employee
```

and the fields are

```
 name,enroll_id,post,designation,gender
```

now for importing data i have used following:

```
insert into employeeinfo.employee (name.gender) values(select emp.name,emp.gender from employeedata.employee emp);
```

but every time it is showing `sql syntax error`. Please help for the following code and if there is any other way then please suggest it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off the insert should read `(name, gender)` not `(name.gender)`. Try splitting up the select statements so that you have one for each column:

```
insert into employeeinfo.employee (name, gender) values
((select emp.name from employeedata.employee as emp), (select emp.gender from employeedata.employee as emp));
```

or get rid of the `values` part:

```
insert into employeeinfo.employee (name, gender)
select emp.name, emp.gender from employeedata.employee as emp;
```